# Why does the compiler not see this function header?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

My function header is this:

```
void FileIO::write(LinkedList<Librarian>& librarians, int numlibrarians,
                   LinkedList<Patron>& patrons, int numpatrons,
                   LinkedList<LinkedList<Item> >[] items, int numitems,
                   int currid)
```

The header in my .h is this:

```
void write(LinkedList<Librarian>&, int, LinkedList<Patron>&, int,
           LinkedList<LinkedList<Item> >[], int, int);
```

And yet, when I try to compile my program I get this error:

```
FileIO.cpp:923: error: prototype for ‘void FileIO::write(
LinkedList<Librarian>&, int, LinkedList<Patron>&, int,
LinkedList<LinkedList<Item> >*)’ does not match any in class ‘FileIO’
```

Why would this be? It seems like every one of my headers where I put `> >[]` is not recognized. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Please put some newlines in your code blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is C++ so `LinkedList<LinkedList<Item> >[] items` doesn't make sense since this is a Java construct. Actually the parser is bombing out early somehow thinking the [] is some token which is indeed odd. Replace with `LinkedList<LinkedList<Item> > items[]` and you should be good.

Comment: Indeed. Took Java last two semester and then this semester they switched me to C++. It's the end of the semester and I still haven't gotten used to the syntax. Thanks to everybody who answered.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Item> >[] items
```

to

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Item> > items[]
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `write()` function at line 923 is missing two integer parameters that are needed to make it correspond to the declarations.

Comment: I think the missing `int` parameters reflect that the compiler aborted parsing the function when it saw and couldn't make sense of `[] items` and not that the `int`s were missing from the code.  At least, I hope the original poster is talking about the right line of code.